# Converting Metasploit module to standalone Python script

Tags: linux, exploit, metasploit, python, ruby

How easy is to convert Ruby code to Python code and to change [Metasploit module](https://lab.mediaservice.net/code/sip_digest_leak.rb) into standalone Python script for Linux?

Comment: Likely directly proportional to your knowledge of Ruby and Python.

Comment: This is not an InfoSec question. This is a pure Ruby to Python conversion question.